# How to create a enhanced HTML TransferBox with an attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to create an enhanced transferbox, using HTML, JavaScript and JQuery.

I have a set of options a user can select from and associate with an attribute. The selection and deselection must be accomplished with two SELECT HTML elements (i.e., a transferbox). For example, these options can be a list of skill names.

When the 'add' button is clicked, the option(s) selected in the first SELECT element, along with an attribute (e.g. number of years from a text box) must be transferred from the source SELECT element to selected/destination SELECT element. The attribute must be displayed along with the item text in this second SELECT element (for example, the item displays the skill and the number of years).

When the 'remove' button is clicked, the selected option(s) in the second SELECT element must be moved back to the first SELECT element (in the original format .. without the attribute).

JSON should be the data format for initial selection setup and saving latest selections.

I want an initial set of selections and attributes to be set via JSON in an a hidden input field. I want the final set of selections to be saved to JSON in the same hidden input field.

Example HTML:

```html
    <input type="hidden" id="SelectionsId" value='[{ "id": "2", "attribute":"15"},{ "id": "4", "attribute":"3" }]' />
    <!--<input type="hidden" id="SelectionsId" value='[]' />-->
    
    <div>
        <select class="MultiSelect" multiple="multiple" id="SelectFromId">
            <option value="1">.NET</option>
            <option value="2">C#</option>
            <option value="3">SQL Server</option>
            <option value="4">jQuery</option>
            <option value="5">Oracle</option>
            <option value="6">WPF</option>
        </select>

        <div style="float:left; margin-top:3%; padding:8px;">
            <div>
                <span>Years:</span>
                <input id="YearsId" type="number" value="1" style="width:36px;" />
                <button title="Add selected" id="includeBtnId">⇾</button>
            </div>
            <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:16%;">
                <button title="Remove selected" id="removeBtnId">⇽</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <select class="MultiSelect" multiple="multiple" id="SelectToId"></select>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <div style="margin-top:40px;margin-left:200px;">
        <button onclick="SaveFinalSelections();">Save</button>
    </div>
```

Example CSS:

```css
    <style>
        .MultiSelect {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            float: left;
        }
    </style>
```

Visual of requirement:

[image]

Comment: **You are trying to self-answer, at the same time.** Asked time:    `2017-12-03 01:58:32Z`
Answered time: `2017-12-03 01:58:32Z`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution to the challenge. The variables being setup at the start make this solution easy to configure and maintain.

When the page gets displayed, the **SetupInitialSelections** method looks at the JSON data in the hidden input field and populates the selected items.

When the 'Save' button clicked, the current selections are converted to JSON and placed back in the hidden input field.

Invisible character \u200C is introduced to delimit the item text and the attribute during display. This comes in to use if the item has to be removed and the original item text has to be determined so it can be placed back in the source SELECT element.

The **selectNewItem** variable can be set to true if you would like the newly added item to be selected soon after adding it to the SELECT element via the 'add' or 'remove' operations.

This solution supports multiple item selections. So multiple items can be added at once ... and similarly multiple items can be removed at once.

```js
    <script src="jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

    <script>
        var savedSelectionsId = 'SelectionsId';
        var fromElementId = 'SelectFromId';
        var toElementId = 'SelectToId';
        var includeButtonId = 'includeBtnId';
        var removeButtonId = 'removeBtnId';
        var extraElementId = 'YearsId';
        var extraPrefix = " (";
        var extraSuffix = " years)";
        var noItemsToIncludeMessage = 'Select item(s) to include.';
        var noItemsToRemoveMessage = 'Select item(s) to remove.';
        var selectNewItem = false;
        var hiddenSeparator = '\u200C'; // invisible seperator character 

        $(document).ready(function () {
            SetupInitialSelections();

            //when button clicked, include selected item(s)
            $("#" + includeButtonId).click(function (e) {
                var selectedOpts = $('#' + fromElementId + ' option:selected');
                if (selectedOpts.length == 0) {
                    alert(noItemsToIncludeMessage);
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return;
                }
                var attribute = $("#" + extraElementId).val();
                selectedOpts.each(function () {
                    var newItem = $('<option>', { value: $(this).val(), text: $(this).text() + hiddenSeparator + extraPrefix + attribute + extraSuffix });
                    $('#' + toElementId).append(newItem);
                    if (selectNewItem) {
                        newItem.prop('selected', true);
                    }
                });
                $(selectedOpts).remove();
                e.preventDefault();
            });
            //when button clicked, remove selected item(s)
            $("#" + removeButtonId).click(function (e) {
                var selectedOpts = $('#' + toElementId + ' option:selected');
                if (selectedOpts.length == 0) {
                    alert(noItemsToRemoveMessage);
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return;
                }
                selectedOpts.each(function () {
                    var textComponents = $(this).text().split(hiddenSeparator);
                    var textOnly = textComponents[0];
                    var newItem = $('<option>', { value: $(this).val(), text: textOnly });
                    $('#' + fromElementId).append(newItem);
                    if (selectNewItem) {
                        newItem.prop('selected', true);
                    }
                });
                $(selectedOpts).remove();
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });

        // Setup/load initial selections 
        function SetupInitialSelections() {
            var data = jQuery.parseJSON($("#" + savedSelectionsId).val());
            $.each(data, function (id, item) {
                var sourceItem = $("#" + fromElementId + " option[value='" + item.id + "']");
                var newText = sourceItem.text() + hiddenSeparator + extraPrefix + item.attribute + extraSuffix;
                $("#" + toElementId).append($("<option>", { value: sourceItem.val(), text: newText }));
                sourceItem.remove();
            });
        }

        // Save final selections 
        function SaveFinalSelections() {
            var selectedItems = $("#" + toElementId + " option");
            var values = $.map(selectedItems, function (option) {
                var textComponents = option.text.split(hiddenSeparator);
                var attribute = textComponents[1].substring(extraPrefix.length);
                var attribute = attribute.substring(0, attribute.length - extraSuffix.length);
                return '{"id":"' + option.value + '","attribute":"' + attribute + '"}';
            });
            $("#" + savedSelectionsId).val("[" + values + "]");
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: **You are trying to self-answer, at the same time.** Asked time:    `2017-12-03 01:58:32Z`
Answered time: `2017-12-03 01:58:32Z`.

Comment: Correct. I am sharing a solution to a challenge that I faced myself. Please refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer